# AngularJS - Sidebar content not change while different login type

Tags: angularjs, authentication

I have two user type.

1 - admin
2 - company

First time while I am login as a admin my page working fine. But while I am logout and login again as a cumpany my previous login admin menu still present in my page. Please check my code.

```
function config($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $ocLazyLoadProvider, IdleProvider, KeepaliveProvider) {    
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/dashboards/dashboard");

    $ocLazyLoadProvider.config({
        /* Set to true if you want to see what and when is dynamically loaded*/
        debug: false
    });

    $stateProvider
          .state('dashboard', {
                abstract: true,
                url: "/dashboards",
                templateUrl: "views/dashboards.html"
            })
           .state('login', {
                url: "/login",
                templateUrl: "views/login.html",
                controller: "loginCtrl",
                hideMenus: true,
                data: {pageTitle: 'Login', specialClass: 'gray-bg'},
                resolve: {
                    loadPlugin: function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                        return $ocLazyLoad.load([
                            {
                                insertBefore: '#loadBefore',
                                name: 'toaster',
                                files: ['js/plugins/toastr/toastr.min.js', 'css/plugins/toastr/toastr.min.css']
                            }
                        ]);
                    }
                }
            }).state('logout', {
                url: "/logout",
                templateUrl: "",
                controller: "LogoutController"
            });

}

function loginCtrl($scope, $http, $location, $rootScope, toaster) {
    $scope.message = '';
    $scope.login = function() {
        var request = $http({
            method: "post",
            url: "users/ajaxLogin.php",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                email: $scope.email,
                password: $scope.password
            },
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        });
        request.success(function(data) {
            if (data.success == true) {
                $scope.message = data.msg;
                $scope.class = "alert-success";
                //$window.location.href = '#/dashboards/dashboard';
                $location.path('/dashboards.dashboard');
            }
            else {
                //$scope.class = "alert-danger";
                //$scope.message = data.msg;
                toaster.pop({
                    type: 'error',
                    title: 'Login Error',
                    body: data.msg,
                    showCloseButton: true,
                });
            }
        });
    }
}


function LogoutController($location, $http, $rootScope, $templateCache, $scope) {
    this.logout = function() {
        var request = $http({
            method: "post",
            url: "users/ajaxLogout",
            dataType: 'json',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        });
        request.success(function(data) {
            $rootScope.authenticated = false;
            $rootScope.id = '';
            $rootScope.unique_id = '';
            $rootScope.print_house_id = '';
            $rootScope.name = '';
            $rootScope.email = '';
            $rootScope.type = '';
            $rootScope.logo = '';
            $templateCache.removeAll();
            $location.path('/login');
        });
    };
}




angular
        .module('myApp')
        .config(config)
        .controller('loginCtrl',loginCtrl)
        .controller('LogoutController',LogoutController)
        .run(['$rootScope', '$location', '$state', function ($rootScope, $location, $state, loginFactory) {
                $rootScope.$state = $state;

                $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
                    $rootScope.authenticated = false;
                    var json = (function () {
                        $.ajax({
                            async: false,
                            global: false,
                            url: 'users/testLogin.php',
                            dataType: "json",
                            success: function (response) {
                                if (response.success) {
                                    $rootScope.authenticated = true;
                                    $rootScope.id = response.data.id;
                                    $rootScope.unique_id = response.data.unique_id;
                                    $rootScope.name = response.data.name;
                                    $rootScope.email = response.data.email;
                                    $rootScope.type = response.data.type;
                                    $rootScope.logo = response.data.logo;
                                } else {
                                    var nextUrl = toState.name;
                                    if (nextUrl == 'signup' || nextUrl == 'login') {

                                    } else {
                                        $location.path('/login');
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    })();


                });
            }]);
```

**testLogin.php**

```
$user = array();
        if ($_SESSION['user_id'] == '') {
            $user = array('id' => '', 'name' => '', 'unique_id' => '', 'email' => '', 'type' => '', 'logo' => '');
            $result['data'] = $user;
            $result['error'] = 'session not found';
        } else {
            $user = array('id' => $_SESSION['user_id'], 'name' => $_SESSION['name'], 'unique_id' => $_SESSION['unique_id'], 'email' => $_SESSION['email'], 'type' => $_SESSION['type'], 'logo' => $_SESSION['logo']);
            $result['data'] = $user;
            $result['success'] = 'session found';
        }
echo json_encode($result);
exit;
```

**ajaxLogin.php**

```
$email = $_REQUEST['email'];
$password = md5($_REQUEST['password']);
$result = array();
$qryUser = mysqli_query($link,"select * FROM users where email='$email', password='$password'");
if(mysqli_num_rows($qryUser)){
    $getUser = mysqli_fetch_assoc($qryUser);
    $result['data'] = $getUser;
    $result['success'] = true;
    $result['msg'] = "Login Success...";
} else{
    $result['success'] = false;
    $result['msg'] = "Incorrect Email or Password";
}
echo json_encode($result);
exit;
```

**dashboard.html**

```
<!-- Navigation -->
<div ng-include="'views/common/sidebar.html'"></div>

<!-- Page wraper -->
<!-- ng-class with current state name give you the ability to extended customization your view -->
<div id="page-wrapper" class="gray-bg {{$state.current.name}}">

    <!-- Page wrapper -->
    <div ng-include="'views/common/topnavbar.html'"></div>

    <!-- Main view  -->
    <div ui-view>Dashboard Page</div>


    <div style="clear:both;"></div>
</div>
<!-- End page wrapper-->
```

**sidebar.html**

```
<div ng-if="type==1">Admin</div>
<div ng-if="type==2">Company</div>
```

**users MySQL table**

```
+-----+----------+------------+---------------+---------------+
| id  |  name    |    type    |    email      |  password     |
+-----+----------+------------+---------------+---------------+
|  1  |  aaa     |    1       | aaa@gmail.com |  pwd_here     |
|  2  |  zzz     |    2       | zzz@gmail.com |  pwd_here     |
+-----+----------+------------+---------------+---------------+
```

I have posted my complete code. Please check If 1st time I logged in as a `admin` then my `sidebar.html` working fine. I am logged out and again login in as `company` my sidebar content still showing `Admin` Please help me.

Comment: Both login and logout are producing success?
Because if not, probably the `type` wasn't reseted at the time of your logout.
Try to print those variable `type, anme, email` in somewhere to make sure you are seeing the real state of the user session.

Comment: I don't see where you are updating the `$_SESSION` variables for login or logout...  did you look at the network tab to analyze the requests/responses you are getting?  Also it would be helpful to see the code where you are making your login/logout requests